# Hadoop: using NLineInputFormat with compression?

Tags: hadoop, split, compression, streaming

```
$ cat abook.txt | base64 –w 0 >onelinetext.b64
$ hadoop fs –put onelinetext.b64 /input/onelinetext.b64
$ hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar  \
    -input /input/onelinetext.b64 \
    -output /output \
    -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat \
    –mapper wc
```

> Num task: 1, and output has one line:
>
> Line 1: 1  2  202699

which makes sense because one line per mapper is intended.

```
$ bzip2 onelinetext.b64
$ hadoop fs –put onelinetext.b64.bz2  /input/onelinetext.b64.bz2
$ hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar \
      -Dmapred.input.compress=true \
      -Dmapred.input.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
      -input /input/onelinetext.b64.gz \
      -output /output \
      -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat \
      –mapper wc
```

I am expecting the same results as above, ‘coz decompressing should occur before processing one-line text (i.e. wc), however, I am getting:

> Num task: 397, and output has 397 lines:
>
> Line1-396: 0 0 0
>
> Line 397:  1   2  202699

Any idea why so many mapred.map.tasks <>1 ? splitting?
I purposely choose gzip because I believe it is NOT split-able. 
I got similar results when using bzip2 and lzop codec.

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that it depends on the Hadoop release you're using. There is, for example [HADOOP-4012](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4012) …

Comment: Not really. I try both 0.20/1.1.1, and 0.21+. same result. What I want is *NOT* to split (prior to processing). As stated, I try non-split-able gzip too. Same results.